# iOS Development: Crash when loading a UITableViewController and there's no error in the console

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uitableview

I've spent that last two hours starring at the most cookie cutter block of code and I can't figure out why it's crashing, plus there's no error message or any useful data shown in the console or debugger.  I'm simply trying to load a view controller that inherits from UITableViewController and its only instance var is a UITableView object.  Here's the class code...

```
@interface PlayFriendViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
 IBOutlet UITableView *rootTableView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *rootTableView;

@end
```

Here's the code that loads it and pushes it on to the stack....

```
 PlayFriendViewController *pfvc = [[PlayFriendViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlayFriendView_iPhone" bundle:nil];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:pfvc animated:YES]; //<--Crashes here
 [pfvc release];
```

and here's the relevant part of the callstack....

```
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x33bd52d4 __kill + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x33bd52c4 kill + 4
2   libSystem.B.dylib              0x33bd52b6 raise + 10
3   libSystem.B.dylib              0x33be9d72 abort + 50
4   libstdc++.6.dylib              0x31bdba20 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
5   libobjc.A.dylib                0x3347c594 _objc_terminate + 104
6   libstdc++.6.dylib              0x31bd9df2 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
7   libstdc++.6.dylib              0x31bd9e46 std::terminate() + 10
8   libstdc++.6.dylib              0x31bd9f16 __cxa_throw + 78
9   libobjc.A.dylib                0x3347b4c4 objc_exception_throw + 64
10  CoreFoundation                 0x33ac07c2 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 62
11  CoreFoundation                 0x33ac07fc +[NSException raise:format:] + 28
12  UIKit                          0x320e4118 -[UITableViewController loadView] + 188
13  UIKit                          0x320a0220 -[UIViewController view] + 24
14  UIKit                          0x320acd04 -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 16
15  UIKit                          0x320acb74 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 24
16  UIKit                          0x320aca72 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 18
17  UIKit                          0x320ac54a -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 374
18  UIKit                          0x320ac358 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 176
19  UIKit                          0x320a00be -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 634
20  UIKit                          0x3209fe34 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 28
```

**One thing to note:** When I remove the UITableView instance var and all connections to it, the view loads successfully.  There's nothing in the view, but at least it doesn't crash.

Any ideas what's happening or how I can get further information on this crash?

Thanks so much for your wisdom!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem and, like all really puzzling bugs, it was stupid. I guess I don't feel so bad since no one else caught it either, but my view controller should be a subclass of `UIViewController`, not `UITableViewController`, since a `UITableView` object is an instance var of my class and my view controller adheres to the appropriate protocols. Anyhow, fixed it, now it works. That stupid mistake only took me two hours to fix...ugghh.

Comment: If this question is no longer relevant to you, please mark an answer or delete it.

Comment: I think I caught it, see my comment above, you should make the `view` property a UITableView and you're there. Protocols don't really matter, they are mostly to silence the compiler.

Comment: @evan, first off, relax.  second, i can't mark my answer for two more days.  third, why would i delete the post just because i got the answer i needed?  this could serve to help someone else who makes the same mistake.

Comment: @mvds, subclassing from the UIViewController fixed it, it's all good now.

Comment: @BeachRunnerJoe: "fix" is a big word for just replacing a part, I really wonder what the actual cause of the exception was. I still think your view was not a UITableView. But anyways glad you "fixed" it. ;-)

Comment: @mvds I can't imagine why you think this didn't fix it. Look at his code, see where it says `@interface PlayFriendViewController : UITableViewController`? It's supposed to be a UIViewController that's being declared as a UITableViewController. Pushing a semi-UITableViewController onto his view controller stack will definitely crash it. Why do you not think that's the answer?

Comment: @Matthew: I just wanted to point out that the reason for the crash was (probably) a wrongly connected view. And if it wasn't, I would just like to know what was. Just to learn from it. Exceptions do tell some story. And from the 3 lines of code here we cannot be sure that "it's supposed to be a UIViewController". Also, I would like to know why the exception wasn't properly caught. But I guess we'll never know.

Answer (score 1):

Are you @synthesizing rootTableView?

Comment: fixed it, see stupid answer below if you're interested.  thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The failure occurs when the new `viewController` is attempting to load the view, which implies that there's some kind of problem with the .xib or, more likely, connections to the .xib.

I would guess that your `UITableView` in the .xib is pointing to an invalid delegate or dataSource, or even more likely, the outlet is pointing to something that doesn't exist. Perhaps you changed the name of the tableView outlet or of the `viewController`.

Comment: i didn't change the name of the view controller, but i at one point, changed the name of the .xib file.  even still, i deleted the .xib file and recreated it from scratch and still it's crashing.  this is so puzzling!

Comment: fixed it, see stupid answer below if you're interested.  thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There should be an exception logged to the console, but if it somehow doesn't reach it, try putting the crashing line in a `@try {} @catch () {}` block, print the exception and then terminate (or not).

Comment: thanks, mvds, i tried this try/catch block but it still just crashes, it doesn't even catch the exception

Comment: @BeachRunnerJoe: most probably not the situation, but could you try and replace `release` with `autorelease`? I have seen very rare circumstances where it actually seemed to matter (although it shouldn't) because the called method apparently didn't `retain` it quickly enough.

Comment: i'll try, but it's crashing before it even gets to the release statement.

Comment: yeah, it's still crashing.  any thoughts on how i can get more information on the crash?  thanks again!

Comment: fixed it, see stupid answer below if you're interested.  thanks again for your help!

Comment: wait: is the `view` property of the `UITableViewController` (or your subclass) connected to a `UITableView`? If not, that would normally lead to an exception I think. And I suspect it's not, since you created an extra outlet for it.

Comment: no, the view property is connected to the view in the .xib file.  it's all good tho, it's working now.